# Undefined reference Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm working with Android NDK and my code appears when compiling undefined reference to `AVI_open_input_file`, and the eclipse appears `Could not find Symbol AVI_open_input_file in index`, this library I have in the project, but does not take into account as if not exist, and been looking at forums and could not fix it

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
# LOCAL_MODULE := main 
LOCAL_MODULE := PrincipalEncoder 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := PrincipalEncoder.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -llog 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) 
# second lib, which will depend on and include the first one 
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := avilib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := avilib.c 
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libstlport_static
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're linking the library to the build?

Comment: In the Android.mk file I link

Comment: What link are you talking about? Anyway do not post links, paste the file here.

Comment: LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#LOCAL_MODULE := main
LOCAL_MODULE := PrincipalEncoder


LOCAL_SRC_FILES := PrincipalEncoder.cpp


LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# second lib, which will depend on and include the first one

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := avilib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := avilib.c

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libstlport_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Answer (score 0):

Your Android.mk builds two shared libraries, but does not declare dependencies between them. You probably want to use the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := PrincipalEncoder 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := PrincipalEncoder.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -llog 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := avlib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) 

include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := avlib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := avilib.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```